# The "LinkAssemblies" Task Failed Unexpectedly. Xamarin.Forms 3.4.0.1009999 Update

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

After updating to Xamarin.Forms 3.4.0.1009999, I get the following error when trying to run the application in release mode - `The "LinkAssemblies"  Task Failed Unexpectedly`

I've searched this error and seen multiple threads on this issue but they were all previous versions of xamarin and non of the suggested solution seemed to work.

What I have tried though is:

- Clearing bin and obj folders then rebuilding the solution.
- Changing the `linker behaviour` (turning it off), which actually works but a huge application is not an option.
- Tried cleaning and building, instead of rebuilding, which is essentially the same thing, it was worth a shot though, it worked for someone else previously
- Deleting and re-adding the Xamarin.Forms package from the Xamarin.Android project

  log:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(5,5): Error MSB4018: The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'Android.Views.ScaleGestureDetector Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.GestureManager::InitializeScaleDetector()' in assembly: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void Android.Support.V4.View.ScaleGestureDetectorCompat::SetQuickScaleEnabled(Android.Views.ScaleGestureDetector,System.Boolean)
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x00013] in <947dd92f52fa43c1922f96c7b9774bdc>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x0004a] in <947dd92f52fa43c1922f96c7b9774bdc>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction (Mono.Cecil.Cil.Instruction instruction) [0x00040] in <947dd92f52fa43c1922f96c7b9774bdc>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody (Mono.Cecil.Cil.MethodBody body) [0x00098] in <947dd92f52fa43c1922f96c7b9774bdc>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition method) [0x00162] in <947dd92f52fa43c1922f96c7b9774bdc>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue () [0x0001b] in <947dd92f52fa43c1922f96c7b9774bdc>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue () [0x00047] in <947dd92f52fa43c1922f96c7b9774bdc>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue () [0x0000a] in <947dd92f52fa43c1922f96c7b9774bdc>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process () [0x00102] in <947dd92f52fa43c1922f96c7b9774bdc>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0000d] in <947dd92f52fa43c1922f96c7b9774bdc>:0 
  at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0000b] in <947dd92f52fa43c1922f96c7b9774bdc>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0001c] in <947dd92f52fa43c1922f96c7b9774bdc>:0 
  at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Run (Mono.Linker.Pipeline pipeline, Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in <947dd92f52fa43c1922f96c7b9774bdc>:0 
  at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process (MonoDroid.Tuner.LinkerOptions options, Mono.Linker.ILogger logger, Mono.Linker.LinkContext& context) [0x00071] in <947dd92f52fa43c1922f96c7b9774bdc>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute (Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver res) [0x002d4] in <947dd92f52fa43c1922f96c7b9774bdc>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute () [0x0021f] in <947dd92f52fa43c1922f96c7b9774bdc>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute () [0x00023] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/TaskExecutionHost/TaskExecutionHost.cs:573 
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost taskHost, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket bucket, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [0x001f6] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TaskBuilder.cs:784  (MSB4018) (LoyaltyWorx.Android)
```

I expected the project to run on the device like it did on previous versions of Xamarin.Forms without having to change the linker behaviour and increase the size of the application significantly.

Comment: Add the error message associated with this!! Just `The "LinkAssemblies"  Task Failed Unexpectedly` is not enough

Comment: There is no other error message associated with that. All I get is that error message, the file and the file path

Comment: There was actually more to the error message, I've added it above. Thanks for informing me @G.hakim.

Comment: No problem what I feel here is that `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll` in your Android project is not referenced properly!! Do you see an exclamatory mark on any of your references?

Comment: I checked right now, there aren't any exclamatory marks on any of my references.

Comment: You do not have something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viTps.png) on any of your references

Comment: What is the version of your Android Support Libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update Xamarin.Android.Support libraries to v27. This typically solves the problem. Don't forget to clean and build, possibly restart Visual Studio

Comment: I tried updating the support libraries, they're all failing to update

Comment: Check this article to help you updating the support libraries - https://montemagno.com/resolving-android-support-library-nuget-installation-issues/

Comment: I had a look at the npm log and there are some other packages  I need to install before updating some of the support libraries. I'll add all the dependancies and then check if everything is fine after all the support libraries are updated.

Comment: Well, then install everything and check after that. Don't forget to delete obj/bin folders, sometimes this also interferes with the build process.

Comment: Now I'm getting an invalid android support library error message

Comment: Thanks Bruno, you really helped me out bro, this seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: You also have to increase the Target Framework (compile)! In my case v.9.0 was necessary, but I think >7.1 would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue wasn't solved as above. The solution was to set Linking to None, based on this post:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/146012/error-during-release-build